# Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.persistence.entity.CustomerOrderEntity.tenantId to java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa-2.1

I'm having issues with the next samples whenever I remove the one to one relationship from the CustomerOrderEntity my tests are passed without problems however when I put back the relationship it fails telling me that a String can't be assigned to an Integer
What do I have wrong in my code?
How can I solve it?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "cust_order")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = CustomerOrderEntity.GRAPH_WITH_LINES,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "lines", subgraph = "subgraph.alternatives")
                },
                subgraphs = {
                        @NamedSubgraph(
                                name = "subgraph.alternatives",
                                attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "alternatives")
                        )
                }
        ),
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = CustomerOrderEntity.GRAPH_WITH_DELIVERY,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "delivery")
                }
        ),
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = CustomerOrderEntity.GRAPH_WITH_ALL_PROPS,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "lines", subgraph = "subgraph.alternatives"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("delivery")
                },
                subgraphs = {
                        @NamedSubgraph(
                                name = "subgraph.alternatives",
                                attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "alternatives")
                        )
                }
        )
})
public class CustomerOrderEntity extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String GRAPH_WITH_LINES = "graph.CustomerOrderEntity.lines";

    public static final String GRAPH_WITH_DELIVERY = "graph.CustomerOrderEntity.delivery";

    public static final String GRAPH_WITH_ALL_PROPS = "graph.CustomerOrderEntity.all";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hash_generator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "hash_generator",
            strategy = "com.persistence.generator.HashSequenceGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_HASHING, value = "tenantId,fulfilLocationId,fulfilOrderId"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_FORMAT, value = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_FORMAT_HEX_VALUE)
            }
    )
    @Column(name = "cust_order_key", nullable = false)
    private String custOrderKey;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private Integer tenantId;

    @Column(name = "fulfil_location_id")
    private Integer fulfilLocationId;

    @Column(name = "fulfil_order_id")
    private String fulfilOrderId;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = CustomerOrderLineEntity.class,
            mappedBy = "order",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @OrderColumn(name = "fulfil_order_line_id")
    private List<CustomerOrderLineEntity> lines;

    @OneToOne(
            targetEntity = CustomerDeliveryEntity.class,
            mappedBy = "order",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private CustomerDeliveryEntity delivery;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "cust_order_line")
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = true)
public class CustomerOrderLineEntity extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hash_generator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "hash_generator",
            strategy = "com.persistence.generator.HashSequenceGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_HASHING, value = "tenantId,fulfilLocationId,fulfilOrderId,fulfilOrderLineId"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_FORMAT, value = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_FORMAT_HEX_VALUE)
            }
    )
    @Column(name = "cust_order_line_key", nullable = false)
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String custOrderLineKey;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer tenantId;

    @Column(name = "fulfil_location_id")
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer fulfilLocationId;

    @Column(name = "fulfil_order_id")
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String fulfilOrderId;

    @Column(name = "fulfil_order_line_id")
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer fulfilOrderLineId;

    @ManyToOne(
            targetEntity = CustomerOrderEntity.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id", referencedColumnName = "tenant_id", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "fulfil_location_id", referencedColumnName = "fulfil_location_id", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "fulfil_order_id", referencedColumnName = "fulfil_order_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    })
    private CustomerOrderEntity order;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = CustomerOrderLineProdAltEntity.class,
            mappedBy = "line",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<CustomerOrderLineProdAltEntity> alternatives;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "order_line_prod_alt")
@ToString(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class CustomerOrderLineProdAltEntity extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_line_prod_alt_key", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hash_generator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "hash_generator",
            strategy = "com.persistence.generator.HashSequenceGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_HASHING, value = "tenantId,fulfilLocationId,fulfilOrderId,fulfilOrderLineId,altGtin"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_FORMAT, value = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_FORMAT_HEX_VALUE)
            }
    )
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String orderLineProdAltKey;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer tenantId;

    @Column(name = "fulfil_location_id")
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer fulfilLocationId;

    @Column(name = "fulfil_order_id")
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String fulfilOrderId;

    @Column(name = "fulfil_order_line_id")
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer fulfilOrderLineId;

    @ManyToOne(
            targetEntity = CustomerOrderLineEntity.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id", referencedColumnName = "tenant_id", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "fulfil_location_id", referencedColumnName = "fulfil_location_id", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "fulfil_order_id", referencedColumnName = "fulfil_order_id", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "fulfil_order_line_id", referencedColumnName = "fulfil_order_line_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    })
    private CustomerOrderLineEntity line;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "cust_delivery")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class CustomerDeliveryEntity extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hash_generator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "hash_generator",
            strategy = "com.persistence.generator.HashSequenceGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_HASHING, value = "tenantId,fulfilLocationId,fulfilOrderId"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_FORMAT, value = HashSequenceGenerator.EXTRACT_FIELDS_FORMAT_HEX_VALUE)
            }
    )
    @Column(name = "cust_delivery_key", nullable = false)
    private String custDeliveryKey;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private Integer tenantId;

    @Column(name = "fulfil_location_id")
    private Integer fulfilLocationId;

    @Column(name = "fulfil_order_id")
    private String fulfilOrderId;

    @OneToOne(
            targetEntity = CustomerOrderEntity.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id", referencedColumnName = "tenant_id", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "fulfil_location_id", referencedColumnName = "fulfil_location_id", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "fulfil_order_id", referencedColumnName = "fulfil_order_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    })
    private CustomerOrderEntity order;
}
```

with the next spring boot repository

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerOrderEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerOrderEntity, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CustomerOrderEntity> {

    @EntityGraph(CustomerOrderEntity.GRAPH_WITH_LINES)
    @Query("select entity from CustomerOrderEntity entity where entity.tenantId = :#{#param.tenantId} and entity.fulfilLocationId = :#{#param.fulfilLocationId} and entity.fulfilOrderId = :#{#param.fulfilOrderId}")
    Optional<CustomerOrderEntity> findOneByOrderIdWithLines(CustomerOrderEntity param);

    @EntityGraph(CustomerOrderEntity.GRAPH_WITH_DELIVERY)
    @Query("select entity from CustomerOrderEntity entity where entity.tenantId = :#{#param.tenantId} and entity.fulfilLocationId = :#{#param.fulfilLocationId} and entity.fulfilOrderId = :#{#param.fulfilOrderId}")
    Optional<CustomerOrderEntity> findOneByOrderIdWithDelivery(CustomerOrderEntity param);

    @EntityGraph(CustomerOrderEntity.GRAPH_WITH_ALL_PROPS)
    @Query("select entity from CustomerOrderEntity entity where entity.tenantId = :#{#param.tenantId} and entity.fulfilLocationId = :#{#param.fulfilLocationId} and entity.fulfilOrderId = :#{#param.fulfilOrderId}")
    Optional<CustomerOrderEntity> findOneByOrderIdWithAllProps(CustomerOrderEntity param);

}
```

and the next test:

[TestCase](https://gist.github.com/juanmcarballo/8420c08f62029dd61efc07817d868107)

And when I try to retrieve a CustomerOrderEntity from the repository it gives the next error trace:

[Stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/juanmcarballo/9d200b087659ae3a9c478dbb5c5f7eca)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add getters and setters for the properties of your domain objects. You might start by adding a getter and a setter for CustomerOrderEntity.tenantId to see if that changes the behaviour when you try to reproduce this issue.